# Работа с элементами gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

На данный момент существует GridViewActivity, где в toolbar'e разместил кнопку "*+*"(который добавляет элементы в список gridView).

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addPerson) {
        addPersonToAdapter();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем, возможно ли данную картинку "+"(или какой то xml файл) разместить в начало моего списка gridView, где по нажатию на данный элемент добавлялись мои элементы так, чтобы картинка "+" передвигалась всегда вправо?

Нашёл примерно похожую [проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451069/new-items-in-gridview-added-at-runtime), но не совсем она открыта.

Answer (score 1):

1. делаете так, чтобы `getCount()` в адаптере возвращал на 1 больше, чем на самом деле.
2. в `getView()` делаете что-то вроде

   ```
   //проверяем, если это последний элемент, то нужно показать кнопку "+"
   if(position == getCount - 1) {
       return new <тут создаем саму кнопку. инфлейтим из XML, создаем "вручную"...>
   } else {
       тут возвращаем View как обычно
   }
   ```

Comment: на данный момент у меня в getCount возвращает persons.size();  добавить к нему + 1 чтоли? или просто достаточно будет изменений в методе getView()?

Comment: @Inkognito, да, добавить +1. Чтобы возвращало `persons.size() + 1;`. И изменить `getView()`

Comment: немного не понимаю как правильно объявить кнопку после return new. Обновил вопрос, где указал как на данный момент у меня используется кнопка добавления.

Comment: что то типо return adapter.getItem(position - 1); ? я запутался совсем ...

Comment: @Inkognito, getView() возвращает View. Вы должны сделать return View, который нужно отобразить на данной позиции. Если на данной позиции должна быть кнопка "+", то вам нужно сделать `return <кнопка "+">`, которую нужно создать самостоятельно